# SQL Profiler: who modified a column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiling

Is it possible to use SQL Server Profiler 2008 to catch which program, run from which computer, is modifying table SALES column POSTED from false to true, but excluding stored procedure 'salesposting'?

I suppose I can use 'objectname' filter for the table, but how to filter the column, the previous value, and the current value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trace specific procedures or update statements through the text data option in the Filters list.
It is likely simpler to add a simple trigger capturing the user / input buffer is likely the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `ApplicationName` and `Hostname` column that you can trace. Just click the check box "Show All columns" that you'll see them

If you want to filter by Stored Procedure, select filter the RPC:Completed event